# Entity FrameWork many-to-many

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-relationship

```
public class Project
{


    public virtual int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual String Title { get; set; }


    public String Definition { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public int CreaterID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Status> Status { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    public Project()
    {
        Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }


}


public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("Kullanıcı Adı")]
    [Required]
    [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Kullanıcı Adı En Az 5 Karakter Olmalıdır")]
    public string username { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [DisplayName("Şifre")]        
    [Required]
    [MinLength(3,ErrorMessage="Şifre En Az  3 Karakter Olmalıdır")]
    public string password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Surname { get; set; }

    public int? CreaterID { get; set; }
    public int level { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Projects = new HashSet<Project>();
    }
}


public class TaskDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Situation> Situaitons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().
          HasMany(c => c.Users).
          WithMany(p => p.Projects).
          Map(
           m =>
           {
               m.MapLeftKey("ProjectId");
               m.MapRightKey("UserId");
               m.ToTable("ProjectUser");
           });
    }

}
```

If I add project , current user added to project users list but project not added current user's projects list 
This is my project add code

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Project proje,Status status)
    {

        proje.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
        proje.Status = new HashSet<Status>();
        var user = _db.Users.Single(r=> r.ID == UserRole.ID);
        proje.Users.Add(user);
        proje.Status.Add(status);
        user.Projects.Add(proje);


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var projeler = _db.Projects;
            projeler.Add(proje);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }


            return View(proje);

    }
```

I Search this problem's cause I did not find , I want to learn why entity framework add user to project's list but not add project to user's list

Answer (score 0):

Your code to add the new project to the database looks correct and the relationship is most likely stored.

But possibly you don't load the `Projects` list with a `User`. If you call...

```
var project = _db.Projects.Single(p => p.ID == 1);
var users = project.Users; // lazy loading because Users is virtual
```

...you will see the project's users because they get *lazily loaded* since the `Project.Users` property is marked as `virtual`. If you do the same with a `User`...

```
var user = _db.Users.Single(u => u.ID == 1);
var projects = user.Projects; // no lazy loading because Projects is not virtual
```

...the projects don't get loaded because the `User.Projects` property is not marked as `virtual`.

Either mark the property as `virtual` as well to enable lazy loading for the `User.Projects` collection:

```
public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
```

Or use eager loading:

```
var user = _db.Users.Include(u => u.Projects).Single(u => u.ID == 1);
```